# webkit-filter grayscale doesnt work

Tags: css

The problem is that in notepad++ it does not come up as grey which made me think that it isn't a correct part of the code but I'm not sure because I am a newbie. The thing I want it to do is to display the image and make is greyscale when  I hover over it.

```
div.img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transition: grayscale 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: grayscale 2s ease;
}
div.img2:hover {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above is perfectly sound, and does indeed make an image turn grey upon hover. Keep in mind that your selector `div.img2:hover` is applying the hover to a **`<div>`**, and that `<div>` needs to have a class of `img2`. The `<div>` would need to have a child `<img>` in order to showcase the hover.

It's possible that you were applying the class to the image instead (with `<img class="img2">`), and meant to write `div .img2` (with a space). The space here indicates that the selector should target any elements with a class of `.img2` that are a child of `<div>`.

Here you can see the CSS working as written in the original question:

```css
div.img2 {
  background: position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transition: grayscale 2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: grayscale 2s ease;
}

div.img2:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img2">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)